# Java convention for storing all defined Strings

Tags: java, convention

What's Java's main convention for storing a predefined set of strings? Right now I have a class that contains all of the strings that I use, but it feels like there's definietly a better way to do this.

This is what I'm doing within a my_strings.java class

```
public final static String s1 = "test";
public final static String s2 = "test2";
...
```

Comment: What are you using those strings for? Is there any relation between them?

Comment: The convention in *any* language is to give your variables names that represent what they are used for. Don't just use `s1`, `s2`, etc.

Comment: Please follow [java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), name your class `MyStrings` instead of `my_strings` and also use capital names for static variables

Comment: Well nomenclature convention would dictate that those strings should be `CAPITAL_UNDERSCORE` to begin with.

Comment: `properties` or public final class with private constructor, and all static final constant fields, or Enum

Comment: Can you elaborate *why* you feel there is a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use resource bundles. Create a file called `messages.properties` in `src` or the subdirectory corresponding to the desired package and add strings to it in the following manner. No quoting is needed.

```
ClassThatUsesAString.stringName=foo
AnotherClass.stringName=bar
AnotherClass.anotherString=baz
```

You can then access these strings as follows:

```
ResourceBundle rsrc = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages");
```

and then:

```
rsrc.getString(stringName);
```

For example, if `FooClass` requires string `quxString`, then add to messages.properties:

```
FooClass.quxString=waldo was here
```

Notice lack of quotes. Now grab it with:

```
rsrc.getString("FooClass.quxString");
```

This does not enforce class boundaries and naming with the class is only for convenience.

If the strings are related closely, an enum may be better, either directly, or specifying message names for different localizations(i.e. an enum contains "ECONNREFUSED" and "ECONNABORTED" and those map to "Connection refused" and "Connection aborted" in one bundle and "conexión rechazada"/"Conexión abortada" in another bundle

**Eclipse users**: Eclipse does this automagically (though in a more complex fashion) with Source→Externalize Strings

Comment: +1 I would just add that if the Strings are related that an enum may be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. If they are related, or they specify a concept, you can use an `enum`. Otherwise, the way to go is to use [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html) with `.properties` file. I would also give these strings sensible names instead of `s1`, or `s2`.

Answer (score 1):

`static final` variables are actually **Constants** by definition, because their values remain constant and can not be changed thereafter.

I assume your `my_strings.java` is a concrete class and not an interface - why interface is a bad idea? read Joshua Bloch on [Constant Interface Anti-Pattern](http://books.google.com.pk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=Joshua%20Bloch%20constant%20anti-pattern&source=bl&ots=yYJiRgrZQ1&sig=9DwZeWoCPS_ZkKyzVZS8-UrQAfU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zmrkUfm8F-fR7AahnoBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Joshua%20Bloch%20constant%20anti-pattern&f=false)

The recommended approach is to determine the **context** of the constant by looking at which classes use those constants?

1. If a constant is used by a single class - put the constant in that particular class and make it private.
2. If a constant is used by more than one classes of but they all are inherited from one another in a hierarchical fashion, then put the constant in the top most class up in the hierarchy and make it protected. So, it will remain accessible to all child classes.
3. If a constant is used by more than one classes and all of them are not linked via inheritance hierarchy, but belongs to same package, then put the constant in a class that is most relevant from a domain perspective and make it package-private (no access modifier)
4. If a constant is used by more than one classes and all of them are not linked via inheritance hierarchy and belongs to multiple packages, then put the constant in a class that is most relevant from a domain perspective and make it public.

In the end, some generic useful coding conventions:

1. Use camel case for class names, like: `MyStrings.java`
2. Use upper case for constants and to separate two words use underscore `'_'`, like: `DEFAULT_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .properties file with your Strings. That way you may handle different languages, changing the reference to the file.